# How to determine the range of a number represented in IEEE-754 format?

Tags: floating-point, number-formats

Given a format: `say 12-bit floating point with sign bit, 5 - bit biased exponent and 6- bit significant with implied bit`, how do i go about determining the range of values which can be represented. I have tried various times and each time i got a different answer. I'm afraid i'm not quite sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Could you edit in your approaches? Maybe we can hint you in the right direction.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: You can use google to find an exact description for the 32 and 64 bit formats. For example 32 bit format has an 8-bit biased exponent and a 23 bit significant with implied bit, so you can adapt your answer straight from that.